# create xml file from object(class) c#

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to create an xml file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
    <METADATA>
        <FIELDS>
           <FIELD WIDTH="8" fieldtype="string" attrname="ID"/>
           <FIELD WIDTH="30" fieldtype="string" attrname="NAME"/>          
        </FIELDS>
        <PARAMS/>
    </METADATA>
    <ROWDATA>
        <ROW ID="00000000" NAME="Peter"/>
        <ROW ID="00000010" NAME="Lucie"/>
    </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

Do you know how can i create it from an c# objet(class) please ? if it is not possible there is another solution to create this file ? 
Thanks

Comment: Please update your post with what you have tried and what isn't working. On the other hand, it can be done in a few ways and we can certainly help you if we see what you have tried. If answers show up, they will more than likely be opinionated because there's no code for us to look over.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani that article is almost 7 years old and does not answer the question about how to generate xml from an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the class by copying this XML test going in Visual Studio -> Edit -> Paste Special -> Choose Xml and VS will automatically create you C# class with properties. After all that you can use XmlSerializer to Serialize this class to wanted XML format.

Comment: It sounds like OP already has the class, so I don't think that part is necessary (although I guess it doesn't hurt?).

Answer (score 0):

Use [xmltocsharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) to convert your xml to c# model

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DATAPACKET")]
public class DATAPACKET
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "METADATA")]
    public METADATA METADATA { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ROWDATA")]
    public ROWDATA ROWDATA { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FIELD")]
public class FIELD
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "attrname")]
    public string Attrname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fieldtype")]
    public string Fieldtype { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "WIDTH")]
    public string WIDTH { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FIELDS")]
public class FIELDS
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FIELD")]
    public List<FIELD> FIELD { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "METADATA")]
public class METADATA
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FIELDS")]
    public FIELDS FIELDS { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PARAMS")]
    public string PARAMS { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ROW")]
public class ROW
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "NAME")]
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ROWDATA")]
public class ROWDATA
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ROW")]
    public List<ROW> ROW { get; set; }
}
```

Then, use `XmlSerializer` to write to xml or read XML

```
//create xml logic
var dataPacket = new DATAPACKET();
var metaData = new METADATA();

var fields = new List<FIELD>();
fields.Add(new FIELD() { WIDTH = "8", Fieldtype = "string", Attrname = "ID" });
fields.Add(new FIELD() { WIDTH = "30", Fieldtype = "string", Attrname = "NAME" });
var rows = new List<ROW>();
rows.Add(new ROW() { ID = "00000000", NAME = "Peter" });
rows.Add(new ROW() { ID = "00000010", NAME = "Lucie" });
metaData.FIELDS = new FIELDS() { FIELD = fields };

var rowData = new ROWDATA();
rowData.ROW = rows;

dataPacket.METADATA = metaData;
dataPacket.ROWDATA = rowData;
var writer =  new XmlSerializer(typeof(DATAPACKET));
var file = File.Create(xmlfilepath);
writer.Serialize(file, dataPacket);
file.Close();

//read xml logic
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(xmlfilepath))
{
    string xmlString = r.ReadToEnd();

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DATAPACKET));

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
    {
        var marketingAllCardholder = (DATAPACKET)ser.Deserialize(reader);

        //add your logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Here is solution :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication143
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataPacket dataPacket = new DataPacket()
            {
                metadata = new MetaData()
                {
                    fields = new List<Field>() {
                        new Field() { width = 8, fieldtype = "string", attrname = "ID"},
                        new Field() { width = 30, fieldtype = "string", attrname = "NAME"}
                    }
                },
                rows = new List<Row>() {
                    new Row() { id = "00000000", name = "Peter"},
                    new Row() { id = "00000010", name = "Lucie"}
                }
            };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataPacket));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, dataPacket);


        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("DATAPACKET")]
    public class DataPacket
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Version")]
        public string version { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("METADATA")]
        public MetaData metadata { get; set;}

        [XmlArray("ROWDATA")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ROW")]
        public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("METADATA")]
    public class MetaData
    {
        [XmlArray("FIELDS")]
        [XmlArrayItem("FIELD")]
        public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("FIELD")]
    public class Field
    {
        [XmlAttribute("WIDTH")]
        public int width { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("fieldtype")]
        public string fieldtype { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Version")]
        public string attrname { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("ROW")]
    public class Row
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ID")]
        public string  id { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("NAME")]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```